# How to download a youtube video using proxy

Tags: video, proxy, download

How to download a youtube video using proxy? I am having to use http://www.proxyvideo.net/ for utube. How can I download a video using this proxy. (in desired resolution particularly 1080p). I tried everything I know of, nothing seems to work.

PS I would prefer not to use any software.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried clipconverter.com from browser. I am actually using it from many months. you can access it through Proxy and you can choose what Resolution you want and you can download.

No Add-on risk.

Comment: I would be grateful if you highlight the procedure.